How to read in and print out standard input until a string occurs and still capture a line?
I have code (let's say a bash script called dots.sh) that I want to run from a python script.  I would like the python script to print out the output of dots.sh as it occurs.  This is my attempt at a wrapper script.
import subprocess
import sys

def run_dot_script():
    # Command to run the bash script
    command = ['bash', './dots.sh']

    # Start the process
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    try:
        # Read output for the specified duraton
        while True:
            char = process.stdout.read(1)
            if not char:
                break
            sys.stdout.write(char.decode('utf-8'))
            sys.stdout.flush()
    finally:
        # Terminate the process
        process.terminate()
        process.wait()

    print()  # Print a newline at the end

# Run the script
run_dot_script()

This works but I want to also capture a line of the output that is just a number.  The problem is that my wrapper code reads in one character at a time so that it can print the dots as they occur and not a line at a time.
How can I do that?
Here is a toy example dots.sh file.

#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..50}; do
    echo -n "."
    sleep 1
done

echo -e "\n"

echo 12345

for i in {1..50}; do
    echo -n "*"
    sleep 1
done

echo


Append the characters you are receiving to a string.  Do something different when that character is a newline.

Or process.stdout.readline()

Your script starts a subprocess and captures everything that sends to standard out, one character at a time.
Once it receives a non-truthy value, you break from the loop, and enter the finally:
    try:
        while True:
            char = process.stdout.read(1)
            if not char:
                break
            ...
    finally:
        ...

At that point, whatever the last string of characters was after the previous newline \n is the string you are after.
So, all you need to do is collect any characters you receive in a string, and reset the string every time you encounter a new character after a newline.
So:
    try:
        last_line = ''
        while True:
            char = process.stdout.read(1)
            if not char:
                break
            if last_line and last_line[-1] == '\n':
                last_line = ''
            char = char.decode('utf-8')
            last_line += char
            ...
    finally:
        print(f'The line you wanted is: {last_line}')
        ...

Note that this decodes the character and overwrites it, since you only seem to need it as a string. And it only adds to the line after checking it needs to exit, since your last line will likely end in a \n as well (as it does with echo)
Of course, if you don't want to print the last line as part of the standard script output, you can just print the last line before every time it gets reset, instead of printing every character as it is read. Then the last line won't ever get printed.
